# C/C++ function recursion

Tags: c++, c, recursion

I have been trying to understand the below code snippet,but not quite getting the logic behind the output.

```
int Func(int x, int y){
    if (x < y)
        return 0;
    else
        return Func(x - y, y) + 1;
}

int main()
{
    int x = 50, y=10;
    printf("%d  \n",Func(x,y));
    return 0;
}
```

The output for the above program is obviously 5. Can anyone tel me what `"+1"` (in `return Func(x - y, y) + 1;`)  in the recursion type method actually means and how it have a execution flow.?

If i just execute `return Func(x-y,y);` then the output is 0, that is fine. But why the output is 5 in the first case?

Comment: The `+1` means to add one to the result of `Func` before returning.

Comment: How do you say that it is *obviously 5*, if you don't know how it got that value ?

Comment: I have executed in Visual studio before posting this question. I was surprised by the output of this. Thats why raised a question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Recursion will proceed as follow:

```
Func(x = 50, y = 10) x >= y 
  Func(x = 40, y = 10) x >= y
    Func(x = 30, y = 10) x >= y
      Func(x = 20, y = 10) x >= y
        Func(x = 10, y = 10) x >= y
          Func(x = 0, y = 10) x < y
          return 0
        return Func(x = 0, y = 10) + 1 = 1
      return Func(x = 10, y = 10) + 1 = 2
    return Func(x = 20, y = 10) + 1 = 3
  return Func(x = 30, y = 10) + 1 = 4
return Func(x = 40, y = 10) + 1 = 5
```

Where `+1` is used to say: "add 1 to the result computed by `Func(x - y, y)` in a recursive call".

Comment: Thank you very much for your neat answer... It gives an exact picture in mind how recursive method executes.

Answer (score 2):

Division is a great substraction, in the end of it. That's the concept this method is showing.
Anyhow, The idea here is that the function substracts the second parameter from the first one each time, and adds to the total sum 1. This way, you check how many times does the first parameter fit inside the other, or in other words, substract. (:

Just explaining the specific +1 part:

In the end , the function returns a zero - when the first parameter is below zero. This way, you know when to stop.

Each time you substract, you add one to the total sum of division, which is the return value in each iteration.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what it does.  I use . to force an indent, to make it easier to see which recursive call we're in.

You call Func(50, 10).

.This calls Func (40, 10).

..This calls Func (30, 10).

...This calls Func (20, 10).

....This calls Func (10, 10).

.....This calls Func (0, 10).  Since 0 < 10, it returns 0.

.....Func(0,10) returned 0.  Add 1 to it and return that.

....Func(10,10) returned 1.  Add 1 to it and return that.

...Func(20,10) returned 2.  Add 1 to it and return that.

..Func(30,10) returned 3.  Add 1 to it and return that.

.Func(40,10) returned 4.  Add 1 to it and return that.

Func(50,10) therefore returned 5.

So, essentially, the result 5 means the number of recursive calls it made, which is 5.

Answer (score 1):

In the base case, `Func()` returns `0`.

If it recurses once, it returns `0 + 1 = 1` (the base case plus 1).

If it recurses twice, it returns `(0 + 1) + 1 = 2` (the base case, plus the 1 case, plus 1).

And on and on.  Thus, the return value represents how many times the function calls itself, which (as another answer says) computes division ignoring the remainder.

Answer (score 1):

Just analyze how code goes. First you go down to basic case (just calling the function). Now you called function five times, each time are different arguments. When x < y, you go back and result you return is 0. Remember that you went down 5 times and done nothing but changing the parameters. Now each time you return back, you add +1 to that result, so first time u go back you add +1 and you get 0+1 = 1, then second time you go back you add +1 to that result adn you get 1+1=2, next time 2+1 =3 and so on.